# How to avoid displaying the leading and trailing spaces in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Attached is the picture where the leading spaces are visible higlighted with red color. How to avoid displaying these whitespaces ? I have tried delete whitespaces extension. On saving the file they again come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is changes since the last commit if your code is under version control system like git. Probably when you save your file auto code formatter restore this space according to your code format settings. You can try to disable "Format on save" option in VSCode settings.